# Issue with notification in audio_service

Tags: flutter, notifications, audio-service

when I Start my App in Debug Mode the notification Widget works perfect. But when I compile a Release the Buttons in the notification bar not showing?

Android 10 on Oppo A15.

Comment: Please explain your question with more detailed information and also show your code

Comment: The Debug App shows the Buttons in the notification and the Release Not???

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.
I removed in the File

android/app/src/main/res/raw/keep.xml

The Line:

```xml
tools:discard="@drawable/audio_service"
```

Now it works and the Buttons are shown.